# How to enable glue to geometry in Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

In Visio 2010 I was able to enable glue to geometry with setting "developer tab → properties → glue settings" to 32 - visGlueToGeometry.

But in Visio 2013 it does not works. How can I enable it? I want to be able to connect to any point of shapes bounds.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Visio
2. File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon
3. Under - CHOSE COMMANDS FROM: -> select ALL COMMANDS
4. Find and Add Snap & Glue...
5. In Snap & Glue check GLUE TO -- SHAPE GEOMETRY

ref. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/HV080900680.aspx

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesnot works for me. And as far as I know, setting properties is the same...

Comment: It did work for me.

Comment: Hmm. What version of Visio do you use?

Comment: I am using trial version of Visio 2013

Answer (score 4):

For 2013 Pro (should be the same for non-pro)

1. In the ribbon you should see a "View" tab.
2. In the view tab there is a section called "Visual Aids"
3. There is a little icon you can click on to expand these options - click on this - et voila

OR

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to get to the same place

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching I found a potential solution. Instead of trying to enable snap to geometry, add a new connection point. It's not perfect, but it worked around the issue (for me, at least).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/add-move-or-delete-connection-points-HP010378181.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, it wont help me because adding a connection point will prevent from glueing to any other point except of connection one...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is glued to what. It is not possible to really enable glue to geometry for connectors, they will always do as they see fit. Regular lines will snap to geometry correctly, but they're not as useful because they don't route around shapes.

Sadly, the connector tool has been improved to be more user friendly.